# Mongo DB get statistics for the data/document being retrieved

Tags: c#, mongodb, statistics, nosql

I am aware of the dbStats and collStats command of mongodb. But they are used to get the statistics of entire db or a collection.

I am in need of a query that can return me the statistics of a document in a collection.

Eg: If I try to find a document in a collection, I get the stats for that document as well. What is the size of the document and related information.

Is there a query to perform this kind of action ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.bsonsize in javascript

```
Object.bsonsize(db.test.findOne({example:"example"}))
```

this will return the correct size of the particular document (in bytes)

Comment: what if I have some projection properties and entire document is not being fetched ? Would it work then aswell ?

Comment: @Code-47 It will return size for only the projected fields. So with and without projection will give different results.